# Load Facebook Javascript SDK into Ruby on Rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, facebook-javascript-sdk

I've looked at other answers to this problem, but, I haven't managed to get it working.

I'm trying to make a simple Rails app, which allows Facebook users to view their events in a nice layout. In order to do so, I have used Omniauth and Devise to allow the users to login via Facebook. Now I would like to add the user's events to an Event model I have. I have managed to get the Javascript SDK working outside of Rails before, but not within it.

I want to load the SDK when the user goes to the new.html.erb view of the Events. IE, I want the create events based on their Facebook events.

In the new.html.erb, I have the following code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : 'MYAPPID',
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v2.5'
  });
//Other Facebook related code goes here
}

(function(d, s, id){
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
 if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
 js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
 js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
 fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);     
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Alas, this does not seem to work. 
In the console I get the following error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined
Am I missing something with the asset pipeline here? Is this a turbolinks issue?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: _“ which leads me to believe that the asynchronous loading is not occurring”_ – where’s the code that loads the SDK?

Comment: At which point/line number do you get the “FB is not defined” error?

Comment: I think it's on the  FB.init({...}); line, because if I put a console.log before that, it works, but if I put one after, it doesn't.

Comment: You’re viewing this in a normal browser, right? Are you call the document via HTTP(S)? Otherwise, the protocol-relative URL used to embed the SDK (`js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/…`) can’t work. Can you see if the SDKs gets loaded properly in the browser’s dev tools/network panel?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using Chrome, v46. In the network pane, I see sdk.js twice. The first one has status 307 (internal redirect), while the second one has 304 (not modified). If I click on the second one, the response contains minified JS, so I assume it's loaded properly?